# How to show App Icon Badge Numbers on Huawei

Tags: android, push-notification, huawei-mobile-services

On Huawei device (Android 9) my app does not show numbers on app icon for push notification. In the settings from the device under "App icon badges" I can switch the "Badge disply mode" between "Numbers" and "Dots". If I use dots, everything works fine and a dot is shown but if I use numbers my app is not in the list and show nothing on the icon.

[image: settings]

I tested the following permissions for huawei but no success

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Do i have to use other permissions or implement something special to be in the list for numbers and be able to show numbers on the app icon?

Answer (score 1):

Push Kit provides an API for setting badges on the server. You can encapsulate badge parameters in messages. When sending a push request, you can set the **add_num**, **class**, and **set_num** parameters to set the badge.

Sample code for setting a badge on the server:

```
{
    "validate_only": false,
    "message": {
        "notification": {
            "title": "message title ",
            "body": "message body"
        },
        "android": {
            "notification": {
                "click_action": {
                    "type": 2,
                    "url": "https://example.com"
                },
                "badge": {
                    "add_num": 1,
                    "class": "com.huawei.codelabpush.MainActivity",
                    "set_num": 10
                }
            },
            "ttl": "1000"
        },
        "token": [
            "pushtoken1"
        ]
    }
}
```

For more information, see [docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/android-badging-0000001050042083-V5).

Answer (score 0):

Try Notification.Builder setNumber (int number).

Comment: I tryed setNumber already. It works on other devices like Samsung but not on Huawei.

Comment: @dilip have you found any solution of this problem yet?